# Shopify Liquid : IF < "certain time of day"

Tags: shopify, liquid

Im trying to display a message in Shopify Liquid if the current time of the user is before 16:00 (London Time) or a different message if its past 16:00. On top of this i'd also like a seperate message depending on the day.

My current code looks like this but im not sure how I can now get an If statement into each case.

```
{% assign day = 'now' | date: '%A' %}
{% assign time = 'now' | date: '%R' %} 

{% case day %}
{% when "Monday" %}
{% when "Tuesday" %}
{% when "Wednesday" %}
{% when "Thursday" %}
{% when "Friday" %}
{% when "Saturday" %}
{% when "Sunday" %}
{% else %}
 Error
{% endcase %}

{{ day }}
{{ time }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out after a little research.
Instead of using the unix timestamp like i was doing i should have been using the hour format

```
{% assign time = 'now' | date: '%k' | plus: 0 %}
```

You can then simply use an if statement such as:

```
{% if time < 15 %}
   do something
{% endif %}
```

Saw a couple of other forums asking how this can be achieved with no answers so hopefully this will help atleast 1 person!

Note: You have to include the `| plus: 0` to convert the time variable to something than can be compared with a numerical value

Comment: Just some quick advice, Shopify does cache the page content, so you may find that this will not work sometimes, and is [generally regarded as a bad idea](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/comparing-time-with-current-time-in-liquid/m-p/503887/highlight/true#M129201)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
{% assign currenttime = "now" | date: "%H%M" %}
{% if currenttime > '1600' %}

  Time is greater then 16:00

{% elsif currenttime < '1600' %}
  Time is less then 16:00

{% endif %}
```